# Django-mobile import error: module does not define a flavour attribute/clsss

Tags: python, django

Trying to apply django-mobile to build mobile versions of templates. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-mobile
Installation is little mess because `TEMPLATE_LOADERS` were deprecated  (Using Django 1.8), so I added `loaders` below according to django documentation. So that may be the only difference between my code and instruction. After this I had error saying that `APP_DIRS` shall be removed so I set it false.

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [],
    'APP_DIRS': False,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            'django_mobile.context_processors.flavour ',
        ],
        'loaders': [
            'django_mobile.loader.Loader',
        ]
    },
},
```

]

Finally, with such settings I get this error:

```
 ImportError at /user/VitalyKotik/
Module "django_mobile.context_processors.flavour " does not define a "flavour " attribute/class


Exception Location: /Users/TheKotik/glboy1/denv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py in import_string, line 29
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a trailing space after `'django_mobile.context_processors.flavour'` (`..._processors.flavour '`)

Answer (score 0):

Did yo add `django_mobile.middleware.MobileDetectionMiddleware` and `django_mobile.middleware.SetFlavourMiddleware` to `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`?